# navigation.push in undefined for contentComponent of drawer navigation in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

React-navigation version: 3.0.9

I create drawerLayout in `react-native` with the following code with help of `react-navigation`:

```
export default createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Pin: {
      screen: PinScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        drawerLockMode: 'locked-closed'
      }
    },
    ListView: { screen: ListViewScreen },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Pin',
    headerMode: 'none',
    contentComponent: props => <SideBar {...props} />
  }
);
```

Inside this `SideBar` component I have the following item touch handling code:

```
<ListItem
  style={styles.listItem}
  onPress={() => {
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.closeDrawer());
    this.props.navigation.push('ListView');
  }}
>
  <Text>Home screen</Text>
</ListItem>
```

But When I press this item I get message that `this.props.navigation.push` is undefined in this `onPress` handler.

I need `ListView` screen to refresh data once shown after navigation action and now put the data fetching logic inside `componentDidMount`. `push` does work for other screens but I feel that this `props` that are being passed to `SideBar` are different.

So **question: How to make `ListView` screen remount/refresh data when is navigated from `SideBar` as described above?**

Answer (score 1):

Please use navigation.navigate() for changing the screen like

```
onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate("ListView")}
```

And you can use componentDidMount() in your ListView component.

Comment: in my settings it's not remounted or even re-rendered. This was my initial solution that failed to work as expected.

Comment: Please tell me your react-navigation version

Comment: react-navigation@^3.0.9:
  version "3.0.9"

Answer (score -1):

You need to wrap your SideBar with withNavigation according to react-navigation's docs https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/with-navigation.html;

```
import React from 'react';
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';

class SideBar extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div></div>
        );
    }
}

export default withNavigation(SideBar);
```

Comment: `navigation.push is not a function`

Comment: This method is used for reaching deeply nested child or can not passed the "navigation" prop directly. So this.props.navigation will be defined as in the react-navigation docs. You should read that document https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/with-navigation.html